# Is my connection too slow?

Tags: halo-combat-evolved

I want to play Halo: Combat Evolved on the PC online, but everytime I join a match, I get kicked because my ping is too high. The minimum 425, but mine's over 1,000. what do I do? Do  I need a faster internet connection, or is it something entirely different? My internet speed is 100 mbps.

Comment: I am not really sure what is causing your problem, but the problem you are having is with [latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_(engineering)), which is completely different from your [bandwidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_(engineering)) of 100 mbps.

Comment: Sort of a duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1878/15643)

Comment: What are tou using to connect? Satellite? 3G? A second of latency is a real lot to work with. 150ms are already stretching most lag compensation systems to the max.

Comment: Minimum is 425 eh?  That explains why I could never play that game without people lagging all over the place :P

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are running into is based on latency, which is the amount of time it takes for data to get from source to destination. A common cause of high bandwidth but bad latency is using satellite internet (It passes a lot of data, but slower). Unfortunately location, and service in your area will have a pronounced effect on both speed and latency. I would recommend contacting your ISP and see if their is any solution for the matter (1000 ping is very high these days). If they do not have a solution for you, find another ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Ping varies wildly from game-to-game. I would suggest you to keep the following instructions while playing online game:

1. Don't open any videos,stream and check if there any problem in your router.
2. Make sure there's no browser .exe's still running in task manager
3. Try to contact your internet service provider and get suitable data plan.
4. Move closer to server

I am sure if you follow the rules, you will get chance to reduce your ping rate. Finally you can check whether it's your ping is reduced or not using [WhoisXY.com](http://www.whoisxy.com/ping.aspx)